# asp.net master page/content page interaction with style sheet

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

Learning how to do a master page in asp.net. Trying to figure out how my style sheet interacts with respects to the master page and content page. I can get HTML tags like body and the style sheet to react. But when I call the ID attribute of a label no styling takes place. What am I missing here as far as interaction? BTW I'm using VS2008

CSS sample:

```
body
 {
 height:1200px;
 width:920px;
 border-style:solid;
 border-color:blue;
 padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;
 }

 #toptext1
 {
 position:relative;
 top:-225px;
 right:-500px;
 font-size:22px;
 font-weight:bold;
 }
```

From the master page:

```
  <body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
         <asp:image  id="cookNookLogo" ImageUrl="images/Logo.gif" runat="server" 
         AlternateText="CookNook" Width="449px"></asp:image>
  <p>
     <asp:Label ID="toptext1" runat="server" Text="Quality Recipes, Hints and    Supplies"></asp:Label>

</p>
```

From the content page:

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/CNMasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true"      CodeFile="Home.aspx.cs" Inherits="Home" Title="Untitled Page" %>

 <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">

 <link href="App_Themes/cn/cn.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

 </asp:Content>
```

When I was doing this without a master page it worked so where am I going wrong with the attributes?

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET or Classic ASP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have something like this instead

**CSS**

```
.toptext1
 {
 position:relative;
 top:-225px;
 right:-500px;
 font-size:22px;
 font-weight:bold;
 }
```

**ASPX**

```
<asp:Label ID="toptext1" runat="server" CssClass="toptext1" Text="Quality
 Recipes, Hints and    Supplies"></asp:Label>
```

As Sean Vieira remarked. The id you assign to a web control is not the same id sent to the browser.

Here you have a good tutorial explaining how .NET manage IDs for web controls.

http://www.asp.net/LEARN/master-pages/tutorial-05-vb.aspx

Comment: The id you assign to a web control is not the same id sent to the browser. ....The things I overlook when learning a new language.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the generated source code for your page, you'll see that .NET has **replaced** your id with a far more detailed id, specifying the container and the section that it is in.

Looking at your code, the id is probably something like: c100_toptext1 (though it depends on the version of .NET that you are using)